# PHP Order Form - Fixed/variable subtotal line?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, product

I'm looking to add a tax line as well as a grand total line under the products.  The tax is fixed at $100 until 30% of the subtotal exceeds $100, at which point the tax equals 30%(subtotal).  This is how I did it when I was originally writing the form in javascript (but realized that php was probably the way to go about this from the get go - am I wrong?):

```
var setup = 0;
  if(gt*.30>100){
      setup = gt*.3;

  }
  else if (gt*.3<100 && gt>0){
      setup = 100;

  }
  else if (gt =0) {
      setup = 0;
  }
```

Here is the template I'm working off of: http://www.dyn-web.com/php/order_form/example2.php

The php code so far:

```
<?php


$PRODUCTS = array(
// product abbreviation, product name, unit price
// follow valid name/ID rules for product abbreviation 
array('prod1', '20"  4:3 (1600 x 1200)', 150),
array('prod2', '24" 16:9 (1920 x 1200)', 250),
array('prod3', '32" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 300),
array('prod4', '40" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 450),
array('prod5', '46” LCD 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 600),
);

// functions for example 2 order form

function getOrderForm2() {
global $PRODUCTS;
$tbl = new HTML_Table('', 'demoTbl');
$frm = new HTML_Form();

// header row
$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell('Product', 'first', 'header');
    $tbl->addCell('Price', '', 'header');
    $tbl->addCell('Quantity', '', 'header');
    $tbl->addCell('Totals', '', 'header');

// display product info/form elements
foreach($PRODUCTS as $product) {
    list($abbr, $name, $price) = $product;

    // quantity text input
    $qty_el = $frm->addInput('text', $abbr . '_qty', 0, 
        array('size'=>4, 'class'=>'cur', 'pattern'=>'[0-9]+', 'placeholder'=>0, 
              'onchange'=>'getProductTotal(this)',
              'onclick'=>'checkValue(this)', 'onblur'=>'reCheckValue(this)') );

    // total text input
    $tot_el = $frm->addInput('text', $abbr . '_tot', 0, array('readonly'=>true, 'size'=>8, 'class'=>'cur') );

    // price hidden input
    $price_el = $frm->addInput('hidden', $abbr . '_price', $price);

    $tbl->addRow();
        $tbl->addCell($name);
        $tbl->addCell('$' . number_format($price, 2) . $price_el, 'cur' );
        $tbl->addCell( $qty_el, 'qty');
        $tbl->addCell( $tot_el );
}

 // subtotal row
$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell( 'Equipment Subtotal: ', 'total', 'data', array('colspan'=>3) );
    $tbl->addCell( $frm->addInput('text', 'total', 0, array('readonly'=>true, 'size'=>8, 'class'=>'cur') ) );

//tax row
$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell( 'Delivery/Set-Up/Pick-Up:  30% of Equipment Subtotal ($100 minimum): ', 'total', 'data', array('colspan'=>3) );
    $tbl->addCell( $frm->addInput('text', 'tax', 0, array('readonly'=>true, 'size'=>8, 'class'=>'cur') ) );

 // total row
$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell( 'Grand Total: ', 'total', 'data', array('colspan'=>3) );
    $tbl->addCell( $frm->addInput('text', 'final', 0, array('readonly'=>true, 'size'=>8, 'class'=>'cur') ) );


// additional fields for contact info
$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell('First Name: ', 'label');
    $tbl->addCell(
        $frm->addInput('text', 'first_name', '', array('size'=>36 ) ),
            '', 'data', array('colspan'=>3)
    );

$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell('Last Name: ', 'label');
    $tbl->addCell(
        $frm->addInput('text', 'last_name', '', array('size'=>36) ),
            '', 'data', array('colspan'=>3)
    );


$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell('Email: ', 'label');
    $tbl->addCell(
        $frm->addInput('text', 'email', '', array('size'=>36,
                'pattern' => '^[\w\+\'\.-]+@[\w\'\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$',
                'required' => true
                ) ), '', 'data',
        array('colspan'=>3)
    );

$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell('Phone: ', 'label');
    $tbl->addCell(
        $frm->addInput('text', 'phone', '', array('size'=>36) ),
            'last', 'data', array('colspan'=>3)
    );

// submit button
$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell( $frm->addInput('submit', 'submit', 'Submit'),
            'submit', 'data', array('colspan'=>4) );

$frmStr = $frm->startForm('ex2_result.php', 'post', '', array('onsubmit'=>'return checkSubmit(this);') ) .
    $tbl->display() . $frm->endForm();


return $frmStr;
}
```

I arbitrarily assigned variables "tax" and "final" to the tax and grand total rows, but I'm not even sure how the subtotal is being calculated in the template, I don't see any line summing anywhere.  I feel like I may be in over my head a bit but I think I can push myself to figure this out with a little help.  Can anyone guide me towards setting this up properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to calculate and add tax as the fourth parameter in php.

```
foreach($PRODUCTS as $key => $product) {
    $unit_price = (int) $product[2];
    $tax = $unit_price * 0.3;
    if($tax < 100) {
        $tax = 100;
    }
    $PRODUCTS[$key][3] = $tax;
}
print_r($PRODUCTS);
```

This will give an output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => prod1
            [1] => 20"  4:3 (1600 x 1200)
            [2] => 150
            [3] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => prod2
            [1] => 24" 16:9 (1920 x 1200)
            [2] => 250
            [3] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => prod3
            [1] => 32" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)
            [2] => 300
            [3] => 100
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => prod4
            [1] => 40" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)
            [2] => 450
            [3] => 135
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => prod5
            [1] => 46” LCD 16:9 (1920 x 1080)
            [2] => 600
            [3] => 180
        )

)
```

**EDIT**

The following calculates the tax on the sub-total and assigns to an array with sub-total and tax. The tax is calculated according to the rules.

```
$sub_total = 0;

foreach($PRODUCTS as $key => $product) {
    $unit_price = (int) $product[2];
    $sub_total += $unit_price;
}

$tax = $sub_total * 0.3;
if($tax < 100) {
    $tax = 100;
}

$totals = [$sub_total,$tax];

print_r($totals);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...  I think the issue I'm having though is that the tax needs to a function of the subtotal, not each item, as it is 30% (if more than $100) of the total order.

I think in the case you wrote out, the total tax of 3 product[1] would be $300, when it should come out to $225.  Does that make sense?

Comment: it does, thank you!  I have one more question from my original php - 

 // subtotal row
$tbl->addRow();
    $tbl->addCell( 'Equipment Subtotal: ', 'total', 'data', array('colspan'=>3) );
    $tbl->addCell( $frm->addInput('text', 'total', 0, array('readonly'=>true, 'size'=>8, 'class'=>'cur') ) );

where exactly in this code is the subtotal being summed?  I see the addinput('text', 'total', 0) line for the subtotal value, but don't see any reference to any variables global or local that have a formula summing my unit totals...

Comment: Maybe it was being done in the javascript? I see something like `getProductTotal` in your code but since I dont have your whole code, its hard to tell. Please accept my answer if it was hepful. Thanks!